# Remove underscore and add financial year in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I am currently working one scenario where from the back end I was getting the value as below

```
123222_D1.123
```

But I need to display in drop down as the date which is coming from db(12-Jun-2020) 2020-D1.123

The above value I was showing in the drop down currently

Here is my html code

```
      <select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" name="vd" class="form-control form-control-sm bg-transparent pl-2 version-drpdown">
                <option *ngFor="let version of vd" [value]="version.versionDet">{{version.versionDet}}
                </option>                   
      </select>
```

Here is my html code for date 20-JUN-2020 Ex

```
<div class="version-label">Version Date : <span class="version-date">
    {{select.date}}</span>
</div>
```

I am trying to remove the value until _ and I need to add the Year. I was trying using `split (' _ ')` but that is not working.

Comment: add a demo code or the way you used split function. It hard to guess from the info you have provided

Comment: i just modifed i will provide what i tried

Comment: 123222_D1.123 what does this mean??

Comment: is `(12-Jun-2020) 2020-D1.123` coming from DB ? I cant see `_` (underscore) here

Comment: @Supercool 123222_D1.123 this is actually string which is kind of version

Comment: and what value you want to extract from it??

Comment: @ShashankVivek there is _123222_D1.123 please don't put minus vote

Comment: I want to extract if suppose the value  1232-22_D1.123 I want to remove the value before _

Comment: @Mahadevan : I have not sire. I am editing your question. Please check that you have extra space in `split` around `_`

Comment: @ShashankVivek {{version.versionNum.split('_') | json}} this is what I am trying

Comment: {version.versionNum.split('_')[1]

Comment: @Supercool. this is correct {{version.versionNum.split('_')[1]}}

Comment: Are you asking or telling me?

Comment: i was asking and can you please tell me how to add year in front

Comment: that is working

Comment: but I want to add year in front@Supercool.

Comment: remove any split at angular and do it at DB side if you cannot

Comment: I am sure you can modify or add another field to your query just for that case with a split at DB side

Comment: what do you mean front @Mahadevan

Comment: @Supercool.i need to add year 2020_D1.123

Comment: @tau in DB cannot touch any thing only front end (UI) was possible

Comment: @Supercool.the year which is coming in select.date

Comment: provide 2-3 records from your DB of what is originally returned (edit your question) otherwise your are confusing Supercool and others

Comment: @tau

for example this is the value is coming from API / DB

123222_D1.123 / 212121_A1.231

what I need to show is 

2020_D1.123

2019_A1.231

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Live:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6hzzvf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

```js
console.log("123222_D1.123".replace(/.*_/,"23-JUN-2020".slice(-4)+"_"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

The above solution should work for your requirement. 
Also if you there are lot of elements. you need to create a custom pipe that does the job.

HTML:

```
 {{version.versionNum | version-change:selectedVersion.versionDate}}
```

TS:

```
import { 
    Pipe, 
    PipeTransform 
 } from '@angular/core';  

 @Pipe ({ 
    name: 'version-change' 
 }) 

 export class VersionNameChanger implements PipeTransform { 
    transform(versionNum, date): number { 
     return versionNum.replace(/.*_/,date.slice(-4)+"_");
 } 
}
```

and also dont forget to import pipe in the app module in declarations

Comment: please add year which is coming in select.date

Comment: what does select.date look like?

Comment: 12-JUN-2020 the value is coming from db

Comment: i brought by merging{{select.date}}_{{version.versionNum.split('_')[1]}} but the problem is need to show only year but it showing as 12-JUN-2020_D1.123

Comment: i am checking in this way 

{{version.versionNum.replace(/.*_/,{{selectedVersion.versionDate}}.slice(-4))}} is this correct ?

Comment: Try this {{ version.versionNum.replace(/.*_/,selectedVersion.versionDate.slice(-4))  }}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210459/discussion-between-mahadevan-and-supercool).

Comment: after 23 hours i can give don't worry

Comment: still 3 more hours needed :) i will give your bounty :)

Comment: I have one issue on start date and end date vlidation is not happening can you able to help me on this

Comment: Yea ask the question on stackoverflow,i will try to answer